# How to calculate totals for a filter with a window function?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, window-functions

I have Postgres 9.3 database, and a table with many rows. I have a filter expression and want to calculate `sum` or `count` for 3 types:

1) expression is true
2) expression is false
3) all rows

Example that calculates the first one:

```
select count(*) from osm_polygon where building in ('dormitory', 'офис', 'office',
'school', 'kindergarten', 'residential', 'public', 'yes', 'house',
'apartments', 'roof', 'detached', 'civic', 'shop', 'apartments;yes', 'hotel'));
```

Is this possible to do all three one query with a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html)? (without unions, etc.)

I have read the docs and other examples on window functions, and this is still completely vague for me.

P.S. I know I can use the `with` clause or nested queries, but just for the sake of learning I'd like to try this with window functions/aggregate expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data:

```
create table a_table (id int, val int);
insert into a_table values
(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3);
```

A query with [aggregate expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
select
    sum(val) filter (where id = 1) sum1,
    sum(val) filter (where id != 1) sum2,
    sum(val) sum3
from a_table;
```

Comment: I see the bottom section you show aggregate expression, that's what I needed. Thanks!